# Add additional preview devices to storyboard Xcode 10+

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard, xcode10.2

Is there a way to add additional preview devices to a storyboard?
In this case, my preview device display does not contain iPhone 7+ and iPhone 6 - iPhone 6s+.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't need to be a separate iPhone 7 plus entry, because iPhone 8 plus is there, and is the same logical size.

There doesn't need to be a separate iPhone 6, 6s, or 6s plus entry, because iPhone 8 is there, and is the same logical size.

Comment: This may be true for iPhone 7+ but what about the iPhone 6 family? see: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html